# If/Else in a query, with group by function

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I've these datas:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+-------------+--------+
|   Date    |  Data NP  |  Type  |    Desc     | Amount |
+-----------+-----------+--------+-------------+--------+
| 10/1/2017 | 1/1/1970  | Income | invoice 812 | 600000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 1/1/1970  | Income | invoice 813 |  60000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 1/1/1970  | Income | invoice 813 |  50000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 1/1/1970  | Income | invoice 813 |  20000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 1/1/1970  | Income | invoice 815 |  23000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 1/1/1970  | Income | invoice 815 |  28000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 10/6/2017 | Income | invoice 816 |  70000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 10/6/2017 | Income | invoice 816 |  50000 |
| 10/1/2017 | 1/1/1970  | Income | invoice 817 | 140000 |
+-----------+-----------+--------+-------------+--------+
```

I would like to get a new table where there's only one date, populated with  *date NP* if > of 1/1/1970 otherwise *Date*. The new table has to be grouped by Desc, so to have  the total amount for each invoice.

At the moment this is my formula:

`SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, SUM(Col5) WHERE Col5>0 AND Col1>= date '"&text($A$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' GROUP BY Col4`

but I'm stuck as Google spreadsheet throw an error as I mix an aggregation result, *SUM(Col5)* with other normal results.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error, you should include all the columns that are not being summarized on the GROUP BY clause:

Try

`SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, SUM(Col5) WHERE Col5>0 AND Col1>= date '"&text($A$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' GROUP BY Col1, Col3, Col4`

Regarding the "if", Google Query doesn't include an if clause, so you you could apply the IF by using spreadsheet functions, before or after you do apply the QUERY function.

Comment: It works, thanks, but how to select conditionally a date (Col2 if Col2>'01/01/1970 else Col1)?